# Neat arrangement for fprintf

Tags: matlab, printf

The following is my Matlab coding

```
fprintf(1, 'Object # \tArea \tPerimeter \tCentroid\n');
for i=1:num
a(i)=s(i).Area;
b(i)=s(i).Perimeter;
c(i)=s(i).Centroid;

end

fprintf(1, '#%3d %15u %15u %15u %15u\n', i, a(i), b(i),c(i);
```

The output is

```
File name #     Area    Perimeter     Centroid
1             44992     9.021421e+002    3.464378e+002
```

How to make the output to be aligned in a neat way as following:

```
          File name      Area         Perimeter          Centroid
this_is_my_filename     44992     9.021421e+002     3.464378e+002
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing regarding your code: the `fprintf(1, '#%3d %15u %15u %15u %15u\n', i, a(i), b(i),c(i);` line is outside the loop so it will print data only for last value of `i` variable from the loop. This is why you'll have only one line printed.

As for beautifying the output you can try something like this:

```
fprintf(1, '%15s\t%9s\t%9s\t%19s\n', 'Object #','Area','Perimeter','Centroid');
for i=1:num
    fprintf(1, '%15.5f\t%9.5f\t%9.5f\t%9.5f:%9.5f\n', i, s(i).Area, s(i).Perimeter, s(i).Centroid );
end
```

Note that field widths of each part is the same when you print header row and data rows.

This code assumes you want to print results of `regionprops` function. In this case `Centroid` is not a single number, but a two-element vector indicating x and y position of the region centroid.

Alternatively, you can do the same without loop

```
DataToPrint = [
    [1:num]
    [s.Area]
    [s.Perimeter]
    [s.Centroid]
    ];
fprintf(1, '%15s\t%9s\t%9s\t%19s\n', 'Object #','Area','Perimeter','Centroid');
fprintf(1, '%15.5f\t%9.5f\t%9.5f\t%9.5f:%9.5f\n', DataToPrint );
```

**EDIT:** If you want to save this to file you should write like this:

```
fid = fopen('YourFileName.txt','w'); % open file for writing
fprintf(fid, '%15s\t%9s\t%9s\t%19s\n', 'Object #','Area','Perimeter','Centroid');
fprintf(fid, '%15.5f\t%9.5f\t%9.5f\t%9.5f:%9.5f\n', DataToPrint );
fclose(fid); % close file
```

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/low-level-file-i-o.html for more information

Comment: Thanks! and how can I save the output in text file?
For instance, the command window shows:
Object # Area Perimeter Centroid